# Trying to install jekyll, getting the following error: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, installation, jekyll

I'm trying to install Jekyll but I keep getting stuck on this error. Here's the output to my attempt at installing it

```
clinch@clinch-VirtualBox:~$ gem install jekyllBuilding native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/clinch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling porter.c
cc1: unrecognized option `-Wextra'
cc1: unrecognized option `-Wno-missing-field-initializers'
cc1: unrecognized option `-Wdeclaration-after-statement'
make: *** [porter.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/clinch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/clinch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/ext/gem_make.out
clinch@clinch-VirtualBox:~$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Configured with: ./configure --target=mips-dec-ultrix42 --program-prefix=mips- --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --enable-obsolete
Thread model: single
gcc version 3.2.2
clinch@clinch-VirtualBox:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]
clinch@clinch-VirtualBox:~$ uname -a
Linux clinch-VirtualBox 3.2.0-37-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 24 15:28:10 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've installed the ruby1.9.1-dev package already. I've tried compiling with gcc 4.6 as opposed to 3.2.2 showed in the output I pasted. I also don't know if the native extension error is making the gcc die. I've also rebuilt ruby from scratch.

Maybe I should try with another Ruby version? Though I know 1.9.3 is supported by jekyll.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The errors you've shown here come from the ancient gcc version you're using. What happens if you use one that isn't 10 years old?

Comment: I've already tried using 4.6, like I mentioned in the OP, and it didn't help at all.

Comment: This particular error you've shown here is because you're using gcc 3.3's cc1, which doesn't know these flags. gcc 4.6's cc1 does, so even if it doesn't work, you shouldn't get the same errors. If you _do_ get the same errors, it's still using gcc 3.3 despite what you may think.

Comment: Cubic is right -- if you're getting the same errors while using GCC 4.6, you're probably getting a PATH problem. Could you show us your error message when you use GCC 4.6?

Comment: you and @Cubic are right. I was working with some other gcc version, which was included in my PATH variable. The system was always using that one. When I noticed this, I, naively, tried to fix with a simple alias. The problem is now fixed. I just changed my PATH variable, I think I could've saved some time if I had checked SO earlier. Anyway, thanks to both of you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Try installing Jekyll from *Ruby or Ruby and Rails command prompt instead of any other command prompt***

I am not an expert at all, so my suggested solution is just a 'guess' based on my experience below.

I am using Windows 7. Although you're using Ubuntu and not Windows 7, this solution might work for pretty much anyone with the same problem.

First, I installed Ruby from [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en). Then, I wanted to install Jekyll. I tried installing Jekyll from *Cygwin*. However, I received the following error (although it is not identical to the questioner's error, I think it is sufficiently similar):

```
$ gem install jekyll
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-cygwin -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -ggdb -O2 -pipe   -fno-strict-aliasing  -Wall   -o posix-spawn.o -c posix-spawn.c
posix-spawn.c:9:19: fatal error: spawn.h: No such file or directory
 #include <spawn.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:206: recipe for target `posix-spawn.o' failed
make: *** [posix-spawn.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/ext/gem_make.out
```

However, when I tried to install Jekyll from *Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails* (i.e. Ruby command prompt), Jekyll installed successfully.

Just in case this matters, I removed the system variable {Variable:Comspec,Value:C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe} before (successfully) trying to install Jekyll from the Ruby and Rails command prompt.